# update paging page when Hiding rows in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` with *paging* enabled. I want to hide some *rows* based on a condition: if `id == "such value"`, I want to set `e.row.visible = false;` in the `RowDataBound` event.

I have succeed to do that, but the problem that I want the paging to be effected? If page one of the grid has a rows that will be hided so page two take its place.

please help , thanks

Comment: filter in datasource before binding may be work..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can implement it this way. However, there is [another approach](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/asp.net-2.0/asp.net-2.0-gridview-filtering.html).